# "It was wrong earlier" or "… earlier wrong"?

Tags: adverbs, word-order

For the sentence, 'It was wrong earlier.' and 'It was earlier wrong', what is the correct usage?

Comment: I never realized how weird the word 'wrong' looks until using it several times in the same list.

Comment: @JoeL. I think you'll get that problem with just about any word!

Answer (score 1):

> It was wrong earlier.

*It was earlier wrong* is ungrammatical in English. Though one could also write:

> Earlier, it was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to put this depending on what you want to emphasize:

- "It was wrong, earlier." This puts the emphasis on 'wrong'.
- "It *was* wrong, earlier." The italics emphasize  'wrong'.
- "Earlier, it was wrong." This puts the emphasis on 'earlier'.